# Laplace equation for a single charged particle

Tags: electrostatics, potential, differentiation

At class we have been told that in an area with no charged particles, the Laplace equation holds ($\phi$ is a scalar potential function) : $$\Delta\phi=0$$

I tried to take the example of a single charged particle at the origin, its potential function in relation to infinity is known as $$\phi(r)=\frac{kq}{r}$$

At point, let's say $r=2$, there are no charged particles, and therefore the Laplace equation should hold.

But I get that $\Delta\phi =\frac{kq}{r^3} \neq 0$. What is my misunderstanding?

Comment: The LHS of your equation for a point charge is a delta function.  It's described [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace%27s_equation#Fundamental_solution).

Comment: And since a single charged particle acts like a delta function,  the Laplacian I was calculating is "incorrect" and that's why I receive this odd result? @StephenG

Comment: @StephenG That's completely irrelevant here, the problem is that OP did not calculate the [Laplacian in spherical coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Del_in_cylindrical_and_spherical_coordinates#Del_formula) correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't computed the Laplacian correctly; presumably because you did not consider that the [Laplacian in spherical coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Del_in_cylindrical_and_spherical_coordinates#Del_formula) is not simply taking the derivative w.r.t. $r$ twice.

Comment: Actually I did use this formula and still received a non zero expression (also WolframAlpha received the same result). Could you verify?

Comment: @Taru The expression becomes 0 rather straightforwardly using the correct formula since $r^2 \partial \phi / \partial r$ is constant.

Comment: You're right, I used cylindrical instead. English translation mistake. Thank you.